# How to properly take averages to reduce data in regression/panel data analysis

Tags: equities, regression, paneldata

I'm trying to do a regression on my panel data. Say I have T=3500 days of data and N=125 firms.

Since Matlab get's major memory issues (which I try to prevent by the usual solutions as seen on the Mathworks site), because my panel was too big, I decided to only look at  700 days of data and to take averages of a number of firms to get N=5.

I discovered that the way I take these averages/medians heavily influences my regression results. If I first sort the firms on the size of the dependent variable and then make 5 groups to average them, I'll get less significant results than when I used another (default) sorting (almost alphabetic).

So what is the way to go in these kind of situations?

Comment: Doesn't this rather fit to http://stats.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Richard The OP might get a better answer from there (especially if she makes it more clear what she's trying to do). More generally, so-called big data issues are important for quants (and if she had phrased the question about unbalanced panel methods with huge financial datasets, then that might be a good question here).

Comment: Maybe but the answer might depend on the use case. I believe it would be best to not average at all but if someone can offer some smart approach I'd be interested.

Comment: Can't help directly, but can comment: 1 if you have major differences between mean and median based results - your data has too much skew. You need to cover your basics - are there outliers, is there a skew in population or in your grouping? Can you transform your data (e.g. power transform, or some ratio) to make it more normal? If 2 My Matlab usually can handle this size of data. Are you using 32 or 64 bit matlab? What kind of regression model do you use?

Comment: @Cindy88, Praise the Lord for bell-curve(s) is all that comes to mind (but then I focused on your profile not your question). Sorry, just could not help it. And back to the topic: I love to help but can you please provide more details. Similar to variance reduction techniques on the Monte Carlo side, much more details are needed what you exactly try to achieve in order to decide on the best algorithm optimization. Care to share the type of regression you try to run?

Comment: My dependent variable is the liquidity of a stock (several proxies are possible, for now I am using the ILLIQ measure of Amihud). For my independent variables I tried several combinations out of {Marketcap, Liquidity of the index it belongs to (3 indices), Number of Shares, Number of Freefloat share, percentage of shares that belongs to the freefloat}. Another thing I tried is to average vertically (over time) instead of horizontally (over stocks), which avoids the problem above of how to sort. Still my regression gives way too high p-values.

Comment: Please define your regression problem more clearly, such as the number of rows, columns, and clusters (panels). It's not exactly clear if the 125 firms represent 125 input predictor variables, or there is a collection of variables represented by 125 firms(?). Regarding software, Stata is very reliable for panel data. How is your dependent variable and all of the independent variables distributed -- i.e., what do their histogram plots look like? If there are right or left tails in any of the histograms then you may have issues regarding the distribution of the residuals ($e_i =y_i-\hat{y}_i$),